# net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: android, mysql, database, encryption

I am using **SqlCipher** for encrypting DB.  For testing my approch i am using a two step process:

1. Create a DB (in SqlCipher) by using a key (ofcourse!!!) open it by checking

   `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.
                   openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dataBasePassword, null);
   if(database.isOpen());`

and  than closing the `database`.

2. Than again Opening the Database using code:
   `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.
                   openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, password, null);
           if(database.isOpen())`

**The Problem:**

Password1:`2DD29CA851E7B56E4697B0E1F08507293D761A05CE4D1B628663F411A8086D99`
Password2:`foo123`

When i am trying the to do step 2 (opening the DB) I am getting the error

> net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a
>   database

I know this question has been asked but there is no favourale answer. So any help please!!!!

Comment: Everything seems to be working as expected, based upon what you posted. Moreover, Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem is when I am openning a DB through a password than its ok. But when i am closing it and trying to re-open it through the same password i am getting the error 'file is encrypted or is not a database'.

Comment: "trying to re-open it through the same password" -- according to your question, you are not trying to re-open it through the same password. You are trying to re-open it through a different password.

Comment: @CommonsWare password1 and password2 are two password for two diffreent DB.

Comment: And how are we supposed to know that, considering that both code snippets pass `databaseFile` as the first parameter to `openOrCreateDatabase()`? Your question does not mention anything about having multiple databases. In the future, when asking questions here about code of yours that is not working, you need to supply a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CommonsWare my bad. Question was not explaining the deatils what it should.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using :

```
  net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.
                openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dataBasePassword, null,hook);
```

`
Use :

```
SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook(){
              public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database){
                database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA kdf_iter = 4000");
              }
              public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database){}
            };
        net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase database = net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.
                openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dataBasePassword, null,hook);
```

Works like a charm